# How do I resolve an error pertaining to a variable not located within my OpenModelica Model?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm currently working on building a heat recovery steam generator and have just started building from the ThermoPower Library and connected an evaporator to the economizer.
When trying to simulate, an error occurs within the OMEdit Simulator:

division by zero at time 0, (a=-458389.9207317767) / (b=0), where divisor b expression is: 8.75988806777792 * Economizer.metalTube.Am * Economizer.metalTube.rhomcm * /*Real*/(Economizer.metalTube.Nt)

How exactly do I trouble shoot this error if I cannot define or locate the needed variables that are causing b=0?
Please let me know what you think about this. Your time and energy is greatly appreciated.

I'm not the best at debugging my models but I have an idea and I have some confusion trouble shooting this. My initial confusion was to verify which variable resulted in b=0. However, upon inspection I noticed how the variable Economizer.metalTube.Nt, Economizer.metalTube.Am did not exist within my the economizer class. I knew it had to be rooted into my class through extensions and partial classes and tried to define these "missing" variables in the text view of my economizer model, but this simply resulted in an error saying:

[1] 11:46:14 Translation Error
[ThermoPower_HRSG_Econ_Evap: 68:3-92:112]: Variable Economizer: In modifier (Nt = 3), class or component Nt not found in .

If you have any advice and/or recommendations please leave a comment below!

///UPDATE: Moving forward after what I've learned from others and implementing their suggestions.///

After reading what you and others have said about my issue on OpenModelica I have come to a better understanding of the situation. However, I am still confused as to what is the best way to move forward to debug my model.

So my "Economizer" model, or a heat exchanger located in ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycles.Models.HE, was having the error associated with the divisor "b=0".

When debugging, the error hyperlinked me to the package "thermal" which pointed me towards the line of code that is being flagged:

```
(L/Nw*Nt)*rhomcm*Am*der(Tvol) = int.Q + ext.Q "Energy balance";
```

This line of code is also being used in the Economizer HE class (ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycles.Models.HE). Here in the HE.mo, the same flagged line of code from the thermal package that is causing the error is also located here. What's making my model cause the divider "b=0" are the variables: L, Nw, Nt, Am and Tvol. These variables are not defined/found in the model I am using when defining system parameters.

What's confusing for me as a OpenModelica user is that those variables just mentioned above (L, Nw, Nt, Am and Tvol) are coded/defined in the ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycles.Models.HE text view of the component, but when I try to define/add them into my Economizer.mo belonging to the ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycles.Models.HE class, errors are triggered claiming:

```
[ThermoPower_HRSG_Econ_Evap: 69:3-94:112]: Variable Economizer: In modifier 
(Nt = 1), class or component Nt not found in 
<ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.HE$Economizer>.
```

Essentially, the errors causing the divider "b=0" are located in the base class of the economizer I am using. However, due to the absence or in-ability to define these needed variables within my Economizer.mo model, the equation:

```
(L/Nw*Nt)*rhomcm*Am*der(Tvol) = int.Q + ext.Q "Energy balance";
```

Is now being violated. How do I fix this issue properly?

///UPDATE: CODE PROVIDED BELOW///

```
model ThermoPower_HRSG_Econ_Evap

ThermoPower.Gas.SourceMassFlow Source_FlueGas(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
T = 331.59 + 273.15, 
p0 = 101325, 
w0 = 169.755)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-92, 30}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SourceMassFlow Source_Steam(
T = 46.45 + 273.15, 
h = 203.22e3, 
p0 = 80e5, 
use_T = true, 
w0 = 21.5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, 90}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensT sensT_WaterIn_Econ annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {4, 60}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensT sensT_WaterOut_Econ annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {4, 0}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SensT sensT_ExhaustIn_Econ(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 34}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SensT sensT_ExhaustOut_Econ(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 34}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

inner ThermoPower.System system annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, 90}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure Sink_FlueGas(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
p0 = 101325)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {94, -70}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkPressure Sink_Steam(
p0 = 80e5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, -90}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Examples.HRB.Models.Evaporator Evaporator(
cm = 480,
exchSurface = 2.752, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 21.5, 
fluidNomPressure = 8e+06, 
fluidVol = 0.01376, 
gamma = 85, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.01376, 
metalVol = 0.01376, 
rhom(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 8055, 
rhonom_G = 1)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SensT sensT_ExhaustOut_Evap(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -66}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder VoidFractionSensor annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {53, -43}, extent = 
{{-5, -5}, {5, 5}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput VoidFraction annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, -42}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, 
-42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.HE Economizer(
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.OpPoint,
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Liquid,
N_F = 6, 
N_G = 6,
Tstart_G = 604.74, 
Tstart_M = 573.15, counterCurrent = true, 
exchSurface_F = 2.752, 
exchSurface_G = 2.752, 
extSurfaceTub = 5.504, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 21.5, 
fluidNomPressure = 8e+06, 
fluidVol = 0.01376, 
gamma_F = 3000, 
gamma_G = 30, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.01376, 
lambda = 19.8, 
metalVol = 0.01376, 
rhomcm = 8055 * 480, 
rhonom_F(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 997, 
rhonom_G = 1)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 30}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
connect(Economizer.gasOut, sensT_ExhaustOut_Econ.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{10, 30}, {44, 30}, {44, 30}, {44, 30}}, color = {159, 159, 
223}));
connect(sensT_ExhaustIn_Econ.outlet, Economizer.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-44, 30}, {-10, 30}, {-10, 30}, {-10, 30}}, color = {159, 
159, 223}));
connect(Economizer.waterOut, sensT_WaterOut_Econ.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, 20}, {0, 20}, {0, 6}, {0, 6}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(sensT_WaterIn_Econ.outlet, Economizer.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, 54}, {0, 54}, {0, 40}, {0, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(VoidFractionSensor.y, VoidFraction) annotation(
Line(points = {{58, -42}, {104, -42}, {104, -42}, {110, -42}}, color = {0, 
0, 127}));
connect(Evaporator.voidFraction, VoidFractionSensor.u) annotation(
Line(points = {{10, -44}, {46, -44}, {46, -42}, {46, -42}}, color = {0, 0, 
127}));
connect(sensT_ExhaustOut_Evap.outlet, Sink_FlueGas.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{56, -70}, {70, -70}, {70, -70}, {84, -70}, {84, -70}, {84, 
-70}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(Evaporator.gasOut, sensT_ExhaustOut_Evap.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{10, -50}, {26, -50}, {26, -70}, {44, -70}}, color = {159, 
159, 223}));
connect(sensT_ExhaustOut_Econ.outlet, Evaporator.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{56, 30}, {68, 30}, {68, -20}, {-50, -20}, {-50, -20}, 
{-70, -20}, {-70, -50}, {-10, -50}, {-10, -50}}, color = {159, 159, 
223}));
connect(sensT_WaterOut_Econ.outlet, Evaporator.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, -6}, {0, -40}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Evaporator.waterOut, Sink_Steam.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, -60}, {0, -90}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Source_FlueGas.flange, sensT_ExhaustIn_Econ.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-82, 30}, {-56, 30}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(Source_Steam.flange, sensT_WaterIn_Econ.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{0, 90}, {0, 66}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
annotation(
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));end 
ThermoPower_HRSG_Econ_Evap;
```

Comment: If a variable that is mentioned in the error message does not exist directly in the Economizer class, then it has to be defined in one of the classes that the Economizer class is extending. Look for the keyword extends, and then also check in those partial/base classes. It is easy to get lost if you did not write the model yourself, so reserve some time for it, but you will on the way learn more about the model! Try to draw a UML diagram of the Economizer class with pen and paper, showing which parameters/variables are added on which inheritance level.

Comment: I think you could also look at the source of the  "flattened" model first, to try and trace where these variables come from.

Comment: @matth , what is the point of identifying what base classes the Economizer component is extending... if the declaration of either the "Economizer.metalTube.Nt & Economizer.metalTube.Am" variables aren't recognized or found after instantiating the economizer class? 

On another Modelica Forum it was suggested to add a modifier onto the economizer  component in order to recognize the variables in "b" causing the expression to equal zero. Would this make sense or go against with your experience in OpenModelica?

Comment: @Christoph how do you access the "flattened" model in Modelica? I think the errors caused by "Economizer.metalTube.Nt & Economizer.metalTube.Am" are preventing the model from flattening in the first place.

Comment: Ah sorry, did not realise that your model errors before the flattening stage. I meant the "Instantiate Model" button. Yeah, I think at this point some code or simplified example would be useful.

Comment: I'll attach the code above @Christoph , thanks for checking it out. A second pair of eyes is what I really need it seems . . . But the model can check and instantiate. The weird variable conflicts arise as a simulation error. Let me know what you think about my model when you get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can compare your economizer usage to how the economizer (or even the HE model) is used in ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.Plant?